# Is there any restriction of windows phone apps that directly access the unique ID of a windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any restriction of windows phone apps that directly access the unique ID of a windows phone ? will windows phone reject such apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any application to be successfully ingested into the Market Place you'll have to pass certification and adhere to all guidelines specified in the [Application Certification Requirements for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184843%28v=vs.92%29). Of particular note for you will be [2.8 of the Application Policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184841%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) which states that an application that shares the Unique ID of a device then you must provide a privacy policy, obtain the user's permission and allow later opting out of the sharing of the Unique ID.

Additionally it will, automatically, be flagged as requiring the `ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE` which will show up on the Market Place clients to the end user.